# run Emacs remotely in a webpage?

Tags: web-browser, jupyter

I am just curious:

*Is there a way to run Emacs remotely from a webpage?*

For example, one can set up a JupyterHub on a Ubuntu server so that many users can access server programs from a webpage. Can emacs be set up on a central server and accessed using webpages in a similar way?

(I know non-gui mode emacs can be executed in Juptyer's webpage-based terminal. I'm curious if a GUI version can be also executed from within a webpage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spacemacs folks did it for some time on their homepage using Docker and Xpra, this thread explains the details: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/8634